# Image Picker Expo

Tags: php, reactjs, native, imagepicker

is there a way in which I can get an image path with expo image picker? I have seen that it's possible to get the path name in react-native-image-picker. I want to be able to copy the image path and move the uploaded image to a different directory so that when I access it on another device it can show also? Please help anyone that came across this

Comment: What are you specifically asking? Documentation is very clear you get a uri. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#usage

Comment: I do not want to get the uri, I want to get the url if that makes sense. I want the location of the image, not the identification of the image. That is why I said the path in the question. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Get URI Then you can use https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob to convert to file etc

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an object inside it you'll find 'uri' and this is the path of the image